# Artifacts Problems when bake diffuse texture

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

I'm having problems baking a texture, I can't understand what these artifacts are due to, it only happens with the diffuse, can anyone tell me what it can be? I share a detail of the image.

[image]

Thanks in advance